# What would be the word that is used to describe a person that uses dysphemisms a lot?

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, terminology

> dys·phe·mism
>
> /ˈdisfəˌmizəm/
>
> a derogatory or unpleasant term
> used instead of a pleasant or neutral one, such as “loony bin” for
> “mental hospital.”.
>
> [(Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/dysphemism)

Comment: Why would we need a word for the person?

Comment: You should include the source of your definition.

Comment: @KillingTime Done. Now OP just has to include an 
 example sentence...

Comment: The dysphemic term for such a person is surely "asshole".

Answer (score 1):

The person is, among other things, a derider, a scorner. They may be described as a churl, a grouch, a curmudgeon.

> Derider, from Deride = to laugh at in scorn or contempt; scoff or jeer at; mock
>
> [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/deride)

> Scorner, from scorn = to treat with a great lack of respect
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scorn)

> Curmudgeon = bad-tempered, difficult, cantankerous person
>
> [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/curmudgeon)

> Sourpuss = individual who always has a sad or a negative outlook on issues
>
> [Urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sourpuss)

> Churl = rude and mean-spirited person
>
> [Oxford Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/churl)

Of these I suggest *churl* best captures your meaning.

Comment: I must have used and heard adjectival ***churlish*** with this sense thousands of times, but I doubt I've ever seen the underlying noun ***churl*** except as an archaic alternative to ***peasant / serf***. Semantically it looks like an excellent choice here, but I suspect that if I say *Don't be such a churl!* instead of *Don't be so churlish!* next time the situation arises, I'll be met with some raised eyebrows.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you. I sympathise with your feelings about archaic, although google ngram shows a reasonably constant usage this last 100 years. I suspect I must have read too many Robin Hood stories in my childhood.